# how to get number of characters one can have in a single line effective with page zooming too?

Tags: php, function, formatting

I want to add number of dashes in such a way that a single line only should be drawn, no character wrapping, something like in PHP:

```
str_repeat("-",function_to_know_pagewidth());
```

so that only limited characters are added with no wrapping, responsive too.

Comment: PHP doesn't know the screen size of the client. You'll have to figure this out with JavaScript, depending on your CSS layout. Also, why not use `<hr>`?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I wanted. I just didnt get the idea at the time, thanks a lot.